# How to check whether a column was deleted completely in a webtable?

Tags: vbscript, qtp

How to check whether a column was deleted completely in a webtable using VB script?

I've created a row in a webtable and deleted it. I'd like to check whether the column is deleted from that webtable or not. I've written a script and having a tough time to write the logic. I can get complete row count from a webtable and can loop through one by one. But how to check whether that column was deleted from the webtab?

```
rowCount = SwfWindow(obj).SwfTable(tbl).RowCount 
For i = 0 To rowCount - 1 
    names = SwfWindow(obj).SwfTable(tbl).GetCellData(i, 1)       
    If  names = mycolname  'mycolname is the name of the column deleted  Then
        SwfWindow(obj).SwfTable(tbl).ClickCell i,1  
        Print "col name is present in the table"
        Exit for
    else
        Print "col name is deleted completely from the table"   
    End If
Next
```

Comment: You mean a webtable like QTP?

Comment: So what do you want to check: If the column is gone? But you say "I've created a row in a webtable and deleted it. I'd like to check whether the colmn is deleted from that webtable or not" You created a COLUMN and later deleted it. You want to check if the column is still present. Right?

Comment: The code sample would indicate you are testing a .NET WinForms application, and not a web app/WebTable.

Answer (score 0):

How do you want to identify the column? Probably by name. (The code shown in the question indexes by numeric index.)

It then depends on the webtable´s structure:

**There is a WebTable runtime property returning the name of all columns in a string separated by a semicolon;** iterate over the components of this string and query their names in the loop. If you find the to-be-deleted column in the process, it is still present, if not, it´s deleted.

See http://www.sqaforums.com/forums/hp-unified-functional-testing-uft-mercury-quicktest-pro-qtp/148239-qtp-function-web-table-get-column-number-giving-column-name.html for an example.

**Sometimes, the table is organized a bit different, and the `getROProperty` call returns garbage. Then, you usually find the column names as cell data in row 1.** There, you would need to iterate over the *columns* and use `getCellData` to look at the column name.

Comment: yes it is swftable in .NET. I want to check whether the column was deleted completely from the swtftable. I'll try that above code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @TheBlastOne, the table you see in the AUT (application under test) does not necessarily tell the whole truth about how it is actually structured. The following is a neat trick, which should work for both WebTable and swfTable, to be able to see the actual structure of a table:

1. When you have both the AUT and QTP open, click the "Record" button in QTP
2. Choose to start recording on the open application
3. On the toolbar menu in QTP, select "Insert" --> "Checkpoint" --> "Standard Checkpoint" and click on the table in the AUT

A new window should now have opened, which, among other things, shows you exactly how the table is structured, i.e. row indexes and/or names, column indexes and/or names, etc.